# Word or idiom for someone holding (seemingly) contradictory views

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms

I think some good words would be conflicted, or confused. As an example of context, think of someone who believes in freedom of speech, but, at the same time, they would support banning comedians who make jokes about certain issues that person cares about.

Comment: Related: [Word for person willing to argue contradictory things depending on what suits him](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/100677/142322).

Comment: Your example may well be describing a person who is _balanced_ and able to draw fine distinctions. The freedom of speech vs suppression of sedition/slander/offensive speech issue is far from black and white.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I agree with you. As an American, I uphold the "Free Speech Amendment," but I also realize that free speech is not an absolute. Certain categories of speech, as you point out, are exempt from protection by the First Amendment to the US Constitution. Interestingly, in recent years, "speech" has been broadened to include "expression," and pornographers, for example, have exploited (and have, perhaps contributed to) the expansion of the amendment to include a category of expression which the Supreme Court has never fully sanctioned, at least in its hardcore manifestation.

Comment: The first word that comes to mind is "human"

Comment: @Lawrence That could be "objective" - and it actually fit myself.  I often may argue contradictory views depending on the situation - usually depending on what view I feel is ignored or is the underdog.  That's really an ability to see both/all views - and perhaps the ability to not get too personally invested in either.  Of course, often there may be two (or more) opposing views, but where only one has merits... or is even grounded in reality.

Comment: @rhetorician Not sure it was for Free Speech or Copyright (probably free speech); but in one of the US Supreme Court ruled something like that "lewd expressions" - ie. pornography, although at the time it was probably "pornographic" text - was not protected.  In any case, that decision could probably be used for the other - eg. as a defense for "sharing" pornography.  May have been reversed since though...

Comment: Didn't the US Supreme Court rule not long ago that **lies** - ie. statements that had been shown/proven to be false - where not protected under The First Amendment?  And in any case, there are other laws - like prohibiting slander - which "limits" Free Speech.  Of course, Free Speech is between you and your government/authorities - that the government won't have to approve/censor what you say or write... *I* am not part in *your* right to free speech... I'm not required to listen, to agree, to spread, nor to *not* disagree with your free speech...   So is it then really a contradiction?

Comment: Related, perhaps duplicate: [(50168)](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/50168/13162)

Comment: @BaardKopperud [United States v. One Book Called Ulysses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._One_Book_Called_Ulysses) marked a shift in the legal thinking about obscenity.

Answer (score 45):

There's the term [doublethink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublethink), which comes from George Orwell's classic [1984](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four).

Doublethink refers to the holding of opposing beliefs, and more specifically, *without* [cognitive dissonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance).  Those who doublethink are unaware of any contradiction in their beliefs.

Comment: That's exactly the word that sprang to my mind when I saw this. Doubleplusgood answer.

Comment: I don't think Doublethink describes what the OP is asking about. Doublethink is not simply holding opposing views, it is a fictional method of indoctrination in Orwell's 1984 - for example, in the novel, there are posters everywhere with slogans that say things like "War is Peace" and "Freedom is Slavery" - things that are clearly not true, but if repeated often enough, condition the populace to believe them, so believing that a perpetual state of war and slavery is a desirable thing. It is a type of brainwashing. That is not the same as what the OP describes.

Comment: To clarify, the OP describes someone *freely* holding *seemingly* contradictory views. They have not been indoctrinated or brainwashed, they have arrived at these conclusions themselves, and the opposing views are not necessary actually opposed - e.g. as in the example given, it is quite possible to believe, broadly, in "freedom of speech", whilst accepting that there must be limits to that freedom.

Answer (score 26):

While not really a descriptive term of the person, as you suggest conflicted or confused, [Cognitive Dissonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance) might be applicable.

Comment: Often used to describe 'animal lovers' who eat meat, support factory farming etc

Comment: Cognitive dissonance really describes the feeling of discomfort brought about by conflicting beliefs.

Answer (score 20):

As a single word I'd suggest

***[Inconsistent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inconsistent):***

> - not always acting or behaving in the same way

(M-W)

Comment: Agreed. [(50171)](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/50171/13162)

Comment: Inconsistent while very correct lacks the emotional impact that the original poster might have hoped to find. Inconsistent has very little blame associated with it, and is something you might use to politely describe a hypocrite.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato. I am not sure the term has any "polite" connotation. I'd not take it as such personally.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said it's a polite way to insult someone. Much like "Bless your heart" in the south.

Comment: It's not a loaded word like Hypocrite, instead it describes the pattern of behavior without imposing any compunction. If you are saying someone is a hypocrite you are saying they are a bad person. If you are saying someone is inconsistent you are making no judgement of character.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato - sorry I don't agree with your view. If you are inconsistent you may result unreliable, which, to me may look as bad as being a hypocrite.

Comment: It's possible for inconsistent to not be an insult, hypocrite is always an insult

Answer (score 13):

There are quite a few words that would work for this, here are a few that come to mind (all definitions from the Free Dictionary):

### 1. [dichotomous](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dichotomous)

> adj.
>   2. Characterized by dichotomy.

**dichotomy**

> Noun   1.  being twofold; a classification into two opposed parts or subclasses; *"the dichotomy between eastern and western culture"*

Supposedly some feel that this usage is not correct:

> Usage: Dichotomy should always refer to a division of some kind into two groups. It is sometimes used to refer to a puzzling situation which seems to involve a contradiction, but this use is generally thought to be incorrect

But this is the primary way that I've heard the word used. Seems consistent with the "two opposed parts" meaning.

### 2. [contradictory](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contradictory)

> adj. 1. Involving, of the nature of, or being a contradiction:
>   *contradictory reports about the vaccine's effectiveness. See Synonyms at opposite.*

### 3. [hypocritical](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hypocritical)

> adj. 1. Characterized by hypocrisy: *hypocritical praise*.

**hypocrisy**

> 1. the practice of professing standards, beliefs, etc, contrary to one's real character or actual behaviour, esp. the pretence of virtue and piety

Comment: I would upvote this except that it includes 'dichotomous'. The latter just means having two distinct possibilities, and says nothing about contradiction.

Comment: @Mitch "a classification into two *opposed* parts or subclasses" The two distinct things should be opposed, or it's not dichotomous.

Comment: Dichotomous in my understanding implies more extreme black and white thinking, whereas one can be a mild hypocrite. Someone who has very extreme opinions might be considered dichotomous, but I've never heard it used to refer to someone who simultaneously holds opposing positions.

Answer (score 10):

Formally you would say that person's arguments are 'logically inconsistent'.  I would probably describe it in conversation as:

**self-contradictory**

[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-contradictory):

> having two or more parts that disagree with each other

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few that may fit.

**Multifaceted**: *Having many aspects, sides, or faces.*

**Capricious**: *Given to sudden and unaccountable changes of mood or behavior.*

**Erratic**: *Not even or regular in pattern or movement; unpredictable.*

**Protean**: *Tending or able to change frequently or easily.*

**Versatile**: *Able to adapt or be adapted to many different functions or activities.*

**Multifarious**: *Many and varied.*

**Divers** (Not misspelled): *Many and varied.*

**Hypocrite**: *A person who claims or pretends to have certain beliefs about what is right but who behaves in a way that disagrees with those beliefs.*

**Contradictory Traits**: *Traits that coexist whilst excluding one another.*

**Personality Paradox**: *The observation that a human being’s personality tends to remain the same over time, while their behavior can change in different situations.*

**Mutually Inclusive**: *Able to occur or exist at the same time.*

Oxford American College Dictionary.
Meriam-Webster

Answer (score 4):

### Ambivalent

> Having mixed feelings about someone or something; being unable to choose between two (usually opposing) courses of action.

<sup>[Source](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ambivalent)</sup>

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, or to be precise, "Ambivalence" - the *state* of having mixed feelings. You would describe someone who was in a state of ambivalence (a noun) as being ambivalent (an abjective).

Comment: Also, this reminds me of a quote by F. Scott Fitzgerald (or rather, looking up the quote led me to this discussion): “The test of a first rate intelligence is the ability to hold two opposed ideas in the mind at the same time, and still retain the ability to function”

Answer (score 4):

**Of two minds** (about someone or something) — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/of+two+minds)

> *Fig.* holding conflicting opinions about someone or something; being undecided about someone or something.
>
> *"I am of two minds about whether I should go to the convention."*

Answer (score 3):

***oxymoronic***

From [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oxymoronic):

> a combination of **contradictory** or **incongruous** words (as cruel kindness); broadly :  something (as a concept) that is made up of **contradictory** or **incongruous** elements

Answer (score 3):

Some who speaks out of both sides of their mouth is a phrase I hear quite a bit to refer to someone who says contradicting things. Usually it indicates someone who is just saying what people would like to hear.

> be speaking/talking out of both sides of your mouth  (American)
>    1. to say different things about the same subject when you are with different people in order to always please the people you are with "How can we trust any politicians when we know they're speaking out of both sides of their mouths?"

[Speaking out of both sides of your mouth](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+speaking+out+of+both+sides+of+mouth)

Comment: Welcome to ELU, can you please add sources to your answer to substantiate your claim. You can also have a look at the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out about good answers.

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+speaking+out+of+both+sides+of+mouth

Comment: Please incorporate it into your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Besides **doublethink**, what first came to mind is [**compartmentalization**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmentalization_(psychology)):

> An unconscious psychological defense mechanism used to avoid cognitive dissonance, or the mental discomfort and anxiety caused by a person's having conflicting values, cognitions, emotions, beliefs, etc. within themselves.

Source: Wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

To be used in this way is offensive to some, but the following (non-clinical usage) fits your description - [schizophrenic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/schizophrenic):

> 2. Of, relating to, or characterized by the coexistence of disparate or antagonistic elements: *"I vacillated back and forth without once perceiving that my impulses were schizophrenic" (Shirley Abbott).* - [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/schizophrenic)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean:
**Hypocrite**

> a person who pretends to have virtues, moral or religious beliefs, principles, etc., that he or she does not actually possess, especially a person whose actions belie stated beliefs.
>   Source:http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hypocrite

Answer (score 0):

Although not a decrption of the person, Paradox ~ ([from MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/) )  a statement that seems to say two opposite things but that may be true
but Hypocrite  ~ ([from MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/))  a person who acts in contradiction to his or her stated beliefs or feelings

Comment: The _person_ would not be called a paradox, would they? Please mind it is customary to provide a _link_ to any source you mention, especially when you quote from them.

Comment: I wasn't clear on Paradox & updated the post. oerkelens you must be very busy here on http://english.stackexchange.com/ correcting people.  Seems you overlooked others in this thread though.

Comment: @aloko - As this is your first post, it pops up in a review queue specifically asking for people to review it, in order to help the new poster meet the standards of the site. This is likely why oerkelens has provided you with guidance, but not others.

Answer (score 0):

***self-serving***

From [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self%E2%80%93serving):

> having or showing concern only about your own needs and **interests**

***opportunistic***

From [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opportunistic):

> exploiting opportunities with **little regard to principle** or
>   consequences : *a politician considered opportunistic*

***politic***

From [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/politic):

> *ADJECTIVE*
>
> 1 (Of an action) seeming sensible and judicious in the circumstances:
>   [WITH INFINITIVE]: *I did not think it **politic** to express my
>   reservations*

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of the observer: [irrational](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/irrational).

From the point of view of the person: [misunderstood](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/misunderstood).

Answer (score 0):

A **Moron**?

I see it as; an Oxymoron is a *phrase* that contradicts itself and moron is *someone* that contradicts themselves. I do also tend to think that its more of an intellectual dissonance between two thoughts; say someone who believes everyone was born equal, unless you were born gay, as opposed to someone who is fine with immigration, as long as the migrants aren't moving in next door.

You could also have a **hypocrite** who is someone that acts in a way that contracts whats they say; I do feel this word really has more to do with actions than beliefs - "do as i say, not as i do" or learning through the voice of experience. My father, for example, used to tell me never to have children and never get married. He proceeded to do both some years later...