# Is there a term that describes someone who both seeks to control and is controlled by something?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term that exists implying contradictory aspects of both control and being controlled? A term expressing a simultaneous dichotomy along the lines of:

- controller/controlled
- master/slave
- jailer/prisoner
- governor/governed
- superior/subordinate

One might perhaps use this term of a drug user, who both controls the substance entering the body, but ends up controlled by the substance, or a situation where  a person in authority over another person ends up under the authority of that second person (depending on context). So some examples might be:

> - The man was a ____ to methamphetamine.
> - The man was her ____, her political leader, led politically himself just as often by her words of wisdom.

But does such a single term exist to describe this relationship?

Answer (score 1):

This may be overly poetic, but your question made me think of a phrase from Shakespeare's *Hamlet*:

> Hoist with his own petard

The speaker, Prince Hamlet, was invoking the image of a bomb-maker who is accidentally blown up by the explosive he is trying to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a single word that is as all-encompassing and specific as you requested. I have, however, found an excellent alternative:

**A walking contradiction**, as featured in the [eponymous Green Day song](https://youtu.be/UymN5scMpZM).

Additionally, [here's an older thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342885/word-or-idiom-for-someone-holding-seemingly-contradictory-views) that also tackles the issue of contradiction, with excellent answers that might pique your interest.